# Label unique rows in array

Tags: python, numpy

Consider I have an `5 x 3` numpy array.

```
5 x 3 Array:

 4 5 6 6 7
 4 5 6 6 7
 1 1 2 3 5
 1 1 2 3 5
 4 5 6 7 8
```

Now the output should be as below, as first two rows are same hence make it cluster 0, and third, fourths rows are same, hence cluster 1, last row goes to cluster2.

```
0
0
1
1
2
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? This seems to be something that a simple for loop or `itertools.groupby()` (or a combination thereof) would do.

Comment: I have no clue, I was thinking tedious way, to check previous row and proceed further inside loop

Comment: The output doesn't seem like it could be of big interest. How do you match those values to the rows?

Comment: Let me correct myself in question. I think, updated question makes sense a bit

Comment: `itertools` library, if it is good, I can give try. I was not aware about this library.

Comment: Yes definitely.

Comment: As mentioned, don't forget to accept the answer :) @GirirajPawar

Comment: Just make the axis to 0, As I wanted rows to be similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like with [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)'s `return_inverse` you could get what you want:

```
a = np.array([[ 
 [4, 5, 6, 6, 7],
 [4, 5, 6, 6, 7],
 [1, 1, 2, 3, 5],
 [1 ,1, 2, 3, 5],
 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]])

np.unique(a, axis=1, return_inverse=True)

(array([[[1, 1, 2, 3, 5],
         [4, 5, 6, 6, 7],
         [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]]),
 array([1, 1, 0, 0, 2], dtype=int64))
```

---

```
_, clusters = np.unique(a, axis=1, return_inverse=True)
print(clusters)
# array([1, 1, 0, 0, 2], dtype=int64)
```